# Find the derivative of an inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}-6x+4$.

Let $I$ be the longest closed interval such that $0 \in I$ and $f$ is invertible. And let $g$ be the inverse function of $f$ in $I$.

Find $I$ and $g'(4)$.

**What I've been doing:**

I found $f'(x)=x^2+x-6$ and I found the roots which are $-3$ and $2$, and then I looked where the function decreases and increases.

So $f$ is strictly decreasing in $I=[-3, 2]$ so $f$ must be bijective, and then invertible (right?), also $0 \in I$.

Now I have to find $g'(4)$:

I have that $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ so $(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ and now my problem is: How do I find $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: How about by inspection? What’s the constant term of $f(x)$?

Comment: $f$ is not bijective on $I$, but rather injective on $I$. It'll be bijective if you see it from $I$ to $f(I)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest interval containing $0$ where $f$ is invertible is indeed $[-3,2]$. Also $f(0)=4$.

By definition, for every $x\in[-3,2]$,
$$
x=g(f(x))
$$
so we can differentiate using the chain rule, getting, for $x\in(-3,2)$,
$$
1=g'(f(x))f'(x)
$$
Now substitute $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to find the derivative of an inverse function $f$ given $f'$, we use the method known as **implicit differentiation**. I'll give a different example: differentiating $y=\arcsin x$.
$$\begin{split}
y &= \arcsin x\\
\sin y & = x\\
\cos y \cdot y' & = 1\\
y' & = \sec y\\
y' & = \sec(\arcsin x)\\
\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin x &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.
\end{split}$$
Can you apply this idea to your case?

Comment: Yes, I kinda get what you're doing, but I don't know how to apply it to my case..